# Run 'exec()' inside a function?

Tags: python

Hi folks: I have been trying to execute a 'exec ()' sentence inside a Python function without success; for example when I run:

> ```
> def main():
>     exec( 'from MODULE import {a}'.format( a = 'funcName' ) ) 
>     print( dir( funcName() ) ) 
> main()
> ```

with MODULE.py as:

> ```
> def funcName():
>     return True
> ```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "0.py", line 17, in <module>
    main()
  File "0.py", line 15, in main
    print( dir( funcName() ) ) 
NameError: name 'funcName' is not defined
```

It seems I really missed the point here.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This is unusual code. What are you trying to achieve exactly--a dynamic function import based on a string? Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `exec`.

Comment: huh, the example code works for me

Comment: @maxm: If it does, you're on Python 2, and you should really get Python 3.

Comment: Right, ggorlen, you've got the point; I'm trying a dynamic function import based on a string. When I try de exec() sentence inside the main module but when trying to do it inside a function doesn't work. I really like to avoid collect all the code in the main module. Thks

Comment: @Ernesto: Instead of that, use [`importlib.import_module`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) and [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr).

Comment: Thanks very much  @user2357112 supports Monica. Your answer works for me. Bye